# ionic alerts and passing values into handler()

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am generating ionic alerts dynamically like in the code below:

```
displayMessage(msg: string, title: string, displayButtonText: Array < any >= 
['OK']) {
    let displayButton: Array < any >= [];
    for (var i = 0; i < displayButtonText.length; i++) {
      var buttonText=displayButtonText[i];
      displayButton.push({
        text: displayButtonText[i],
        handler: () => {
          this.setButtonValue(Array.from(displayButtonText)[i]);
        }
      })
    }

    let popUp = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: title,
      subTitle: msg,
      buttons: displayButton
    });
    popUp.present();
  }
```

I am trying to pass 2 values'OK' and 'Cancel', the issue I am unable to pass them to this.setButtonValue() in handler().

Comment: you want dynamic depend on parameter right?

Comment: yes, when no parameter is passed, it displays OK. when I click on the button it emits OK, but when I pass more than two parameters, the second button displays but when I click on it I get OK rather than cancel. Hope this helps?